# Why i get error 7014 when trying Sign in with Apple only on tvOS target

Tags: swift

i have an application with 2 different target: one for iOS and one for tvOS. We need to add Sign in with Apple functionality so i wrote an object to manage that and use it on both target. When i try to login on iOS target it works perfectly but when i try to use it on tvOS target, i always get the error Code=-7014.

Here some code.

```
/// Execute apple login, asking for user first and last name and user e-mail
private func appleLogin() {
    if #available(iOS 13, tvOS 13, *) {
        let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.requestedOperation = .operationLogin

        let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.presentationContextProvider = _presentingViewController as? ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding
        controller.performRequests()
    }
}
```

And delegate method to manage Apple response

```
//MARK: - Sing in with Apple
@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *)
extension VVAuthenticationManager: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    LOGI("Apple complete authorization")

    switch authorization.credential {
    case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
        LOGI("I have user credential")

        if let mail = appleIDCredential.email, let authCode = appleIDCredential.authorizationCode, let authStringCode = String(data: authCode, encoding: .utf8) {
            LOGI("TOKEN: \(authStringCode)")
            // API Registration here
        }
    default:
        // Custom manage error here
        break
    }
}

func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        LOGE("Error: \(error.localizedDescription) code: \(error.asAFError?.responseCode ?? 0)")
    if let e = error as? ASAuthorizationError {
        LOGP("code \(e.code.rawValue)")
        LOGP("code \(e.localizedDescription)")

        e.userInfo.keys.forEach { (body) in
            LOGI("BODY \(body)")
        }

        e.errorUserInfo.keys.forEach { (body) in
            LOGI("BODY ERR \(body)")
        }

        switch e.code {
        case .failed:
            LOGP("Failed")
        case .canceled:
            LOGP("Canceled")
        case .invalidResponse:
            LOGP("Invalid Response")
        case .notHandled:
            LOGP("Not Handled")
        case .unknown:
            LOGP("Unknow error code")
        default:
            LOGD("NOT RECOGNIZED")
        }
    }

}

}
```

Everytime i try to login on tvOS delegate method

```
authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error)
```

is called and i get an unknown error (code 1000). Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem in past and the issue was on simulator. Sign in with Apple required a 2 factor authentication account and, when try it on Apple TV the second phase of authentication will continue on an iPhone or an iPad. 
You should try to run your app on a phisic Apple Tv and sign in with an account active on an iPhone or iPad.

Comment: wow... i spent a lot of time only for this? Incredible, but thanks it works on my Apple tv.

Comment: @Ibbanez Recently, I'm develop an app using "Sign in with Apple" service. For the first times, it worked. But some days later, when I try to sign in, I get notification to my iPhone, but when I tap on that notification, nothing happened, nothing showed. I don't know why. Please tell me if you're still using this service in your app, does it still work?